# Nodal Analysis - solving 2 variables with 3 equations

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice

[image]

There are three conditions:

- before the switch is closed (opened)
- while the switch is closed (closed)
- after the switch is closed (opened)

I think I need to solve them sequentially, because the system has memory.

Here are the system equations (before the switch is closed):

1. \$\Large\frac{9+9}{R_6+R_9}+\frac{9-V_d}{R_4}+\frac{9-V_c}{R_1}=0\$
2. \$\Large\frac{V_d-9}{R_4}+\frac{V_d-V_c}{R_8}+\frac{V_d}{R_5}+\frac{V_d-V_d⋅{(1-e^{-\frac t{R_7⋅C_2}})}}{R_7}=0\$
3. \$\Large\frac{V_c-9}{R_1}+\frac{V_c-V_d}{R_8}+\frac{V_c}{R_2}+\frac{V_c-V_c⋅{(1-e^{-\frac t{R_3⋅C_1}})}}{R_3}=0\$

<s>Also, the current flow of \$V2\$ before the switch is closed is meaningless; if I try to cut the wire between \$V2\$ and node \$a\$ to see the graph before and after, it won't alter \$V_c\$ and \$V_d\$. So it is meaningless. That's why I'm not including this current flow in the equation number 1 above.</s>
Edit: Sorry, it did alter, but for a tiny amount

Some strange things happened after plugging in the \$R\$ values. When I use [Microsoft Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Mathematics) to solve equations \$2\$ and \$3\$, I get the correct graph, but if I try to solve the equation \$2\$ with \$1\$, or \$3\$ with \$1\$, I get the wrong graph. What's wrong?

Comment: Your equations use Vd and Vc, but your schematic shows V1 and V2. You need to fix this discrepancy.

Comment: @BlairFonville \$V_d\$ is the node between \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$. \$V_c\$ is the node between \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. The \$V1\$ will be the supernode for node \$a\$ before the switch is closed. Both \$V1\$ and \$V2\$ will be the supernode for node \$a\$ after the switch is closed. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: My mistake. I see that now.

Comment: Looks good. Nice question. +1

Comment: Maybe a better use is to avoid the use of a `PWL` and use a `.STEP` command with a resistor instead of the switch, having the values `1m` and `1g` (note the smaller difference between the orders of magnitude, something which *may* cause hiccups). This is because the capacitor may need to reach a steady state which will make comparisons more difficult. Plotting a `.step`'ed quantity will let you analyse them in parallel. In this case, `startup` will not be needed, LTspice would automatically determine the operation point.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, I need to switch it with respect of time, so that's why I use PWL, and yes it makes me confused why the current flow from V1 can spikes up to 4A, after changing the model into `SW(Ron={10^(-(10^100))} Roff={1000000000000000000T} Vt=1 Vh=-1)`. It works perfectly with max current up to 14 mA.

Comment: You are needlessly exaggerating those values. The the simulator uses the computer as the underlying hardware so it's prone to the same limitations. What's more, LTspice uses `float`, instead of `double` (unless `.opt numdgt=8`, or greater), for speed. Using such great differences between values is also discouraged by the manual, not to mention common sense. What values do you think those get to be converted into during the simulation? `1m` is << than the kOhms you have, and `1g` is >> than the kOhms, you won't feel any difference, and LTspice will happily simulate it, correctly.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, Ron is prohibited to be zero, so I think it's a hack to value it with `100 zero` and ltspice will read it as zero instead lol, and also I can't use `Roff={10^(10^100))}`, it errors and reads zero, so I use that in order to hack it, and I think LTSpice will read is as `infinity` instead lol. It really works, it doesn't make my simulation slower, it makes it faster, try it

Comment: @Unknown123 There are no zero, or infinite quantities in nature, and neither are there in computer hardware, or software, so your "hacks" are not working as you think they do, but if you think it goes faster, godspeed.